# Are job ads allowed to be profane?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I personally don't find "assholes" to be offensive, but it is profane, and I'm sure someone will object. I wonder: is there a profanity line across which job ads cannot cross?

[image: assholes]

Comment: Might or might not be a reference to https://www.amazon.com/dp/0446526568/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_t1_R-YPAb9SAQMTJ

Comment: At least it's not as offensive as job ads that contain "EQ".

Comment: Take it as an indication of the sort of culture they have.

Comment: <voice imitate="rick moranis">Keep firing, assholes!</voice>

Comment: or maybe it is a reference to Spaceballs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Mv1s4Xj7bk

Comment: I'd hope the answer is no, they can't be offensive. But at the same time, this one certainly seems acceptable.

Comment: Even in the future, job ads are offensive.

Comment: I believe that ads may contain profanities and the viewer should choose whether to apply or ignore. Even if harder words are contained in the ad, it can give the viewer may be a better clue/perspective about that company (like @eLRuLL said). Btw, hipsters (IMO) are the danger of new age, not assholes. Ask them if they have hipsters.

Comment: I find ads for "jobs" where you are under constant webcam surveillance, have to log bathroom breaks and earn a pittance (& no benefits or job security, of course, lol) a lot more offensive. Since those are ok, I don't see why using the word "assholes" shouldn't be

Comment: I don't believe swears, especially mild ones like "asshole", are against any specific rules of ours. However that doesn't mean it's not a _bad job ad_. There is a population of people who will be offended by that language and choose not to apply as a result. I'll ask the customer's liaison to contact the customer and suggest they change the wording.

Comment: I'd argue it's to their benefit to leave it as is... If someone is offended by it, they probably wouldn't enjoy working there.  Everyone involved saves time if those people who are offended do *not* apply.

Comment: I would have thought that in general advertisers would have to follow the same "Be Nice" policy and that word would, at minimum, get edited out of a normal post on the main site. They may have decided that the word wasn't offensive in this particular context. Or maybe they get more leeway since how users interact with ads isn't the same as how we interact with posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Job listings shouldn't include offensive language or language that might make some groups of users feel excluded. If you see a listing with questionable language, please flag it. Our support team will see it and follow up with our customer.

Comment: "Some groups of users feel excluded"... Oh wait, I get it. You're saying that you are an asshole if you are offended by this.

Comment: @usr2564301 You're saying that as if it is a bad thing :)